# Install Chef Server 11 with AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

Now AWS has postgresql service in RDS, So I tried to install Chef Server 11 with postgresql  RDS instance by editing attributes in `/opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/attributes/default.rb`

```
default['chef_server']['postgresql']['vip'] = "rds instance endpoint"
```

and importing database with the following command

```
/opt/chef-server/embedded/bin/psql -h "rds instance endpoint" -p 5432 -U "user_name" "database_name" < /opt/chef-server/embedded/service/erchef/lib/chef_db-f086a97/priv/pgsql_schema.sql
```

But i am not able to achieve that. `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` gives an error
`curl -sf http:// 127.0.0.1:8000 /_status returned 7`

Please help me to configure chef server with RDS instance.

Comment: I think i am able to solve my problem. It is because of encrypted password in erchef config file. I edited "/opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/templates/default/erchef.config.rb" for the same and it seems working perfectly fine now.

Thanks

Comment: Arpit, can you please answer your own question and then mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Ya sure, But it will take me 7 hours to mark it as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i am able to solve my problem. It is because of encrypted password in erchef config file. I edited

"/opt/chef-server/embedded/cookbooks/chef-server/templates/default/echef.config.rb"

for the same and it seems working perfectly fine now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [chef-server-rds](https://github.com/50onRed/chef-server-rds) cookbook on github can be used to install Chef Server 11 with AWS RDS.

Given an iam key and secret, it will provision the rds instance if it doesn't exist in the account, initialize the chef schema, and install the appropriate platform-specific chef-server Omnibus package and perform the initial configuration of Chef Server on an AWS elastic compute ubuntu instance.

Using postgres on Amazon RDS offloads DB resource use away from the chef-server host. It also enables various DB functions like scaling, backup, and restore to be done independently of the chef-server installations. Similar configurations can be written for other db service providers.

Comment: Please summarize the relevant portions of the text from the link as it may fail to load or resolve in the future.